# setting a enviroment secret using github_actions_environment_secret to a different organisation

Tags: github, terraform, github-api

I am wanting to:

```
data "github_repository" "repo" {
  full_name = "my-enterprise/some-repo"
}


resource "github_actions_environment_secret" "read_secret" {
  repository       = data.github_repository.repo.name
  environment      = var.environment
  secret_name      = "test_secret_name"
  plaintext_value  = "xxx"
}
```

Yet when I do this I get an API error that it is trying to use a repo of the same name in my personal org not my enterprise org:

```
Error: GET https://api.github.com/repos/simbo1905/some-repo: 404 Not Found []
```

Reading the docs and trying to guess the setting I don't see anyway to set the "full_name" or the "organization" on the `github_actions_environment_secret` for it to resolve the enterprise repo running on the main github.com SaaS service.

Comment: What is used to configure the GitHub provider in your code?

Comment: Yeah, it is setting “owner” in the gutub block that fixes this, I had an empty block.